Silence mypy arg-type error when using stategy pattern
Minimal example:
from typing import overload, TypeVar, Generic

class EventV1: pass
class EventV2: pass

class DataGathererV1:
    def process(self, event: EventV1): pass
    def process2(self, event: EventV1): pass

class DataGathererV2:
    def process(self, event: EventV2): pass
    def process2(self, event: EventV2): pass


class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_v1: DataGathererV1 = DataGathererV1()
        self.worker_v2: DataGathererV2 = DataGathererV2()

    def dispatch(self, event: EventV1 | EventV2):
        handler: DataGathererV1 | DataGathererV2 = self.worker_v1 if isinstance(event, EventV1) else self.worker_v2

        handler.process(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process2(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process(event)
        # etc...

In the code above, I'm using a sort of "strategy" pattern to process events. I would like to avoid splitting my dispatch method in two methods as I don't think it makes sense and will generate code duplication.
Mypy gives me the following errors and I don't know how to properly type my code to avoid such errors.
example.py:36: error: Argument 1 to "process" of "DataGathererV1" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV1"  [arg-type]
example.py:36: error: Argument 1 to "process" of "DataGathererV2" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV2"  [arg-type]
example.py:40: error: Argument 1 to "process2" of "DataGathererV1" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV1"  [arg-type]
example.py:40: error: Argument 1 to "process2" of "DataGathererV2" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV2"  [arg-type]
example.py:44: error: Argument 1 to "process" of "DataGathererV1" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV1"  [arg-type]
example.py:44: error: Argument 1 to "process" of "DataGathererV2" has incompatible type "EventV1 | EventV2"; expected "EventV2"  [arg-type]

I tried to add an overload function to retrieve both my handler and my event at the same time to force the type to be "linked" (see below), however it did not solve my problem.
@overload
def __handler(self, event: EventV1) -> tuple[DataGathererV1, EventV1]:
    ...

@overload
def __handler(self, event: EventV2) -> tuple[DataGathererV2, EventV2]:
    ...

def __handler(self, event: EventV1 | EventV2) -> tuple[DataGathererV1 | DataGathererV2, EventV1 | EventV2]:
    return (
        self.worker_v1 if isinstance(event, EventV1) else self.worker_v2,
        event
    )

My "dream" solution to indicate to mypy that the type of event and the type of handler are "linked" together.
What I would like to avoid is to set the input type of my event in each DataGathererVX to be EventV1 | EventV2 and add an assert isinstance(event, EventVX) at the beginning of each method as my aim is to have errors when these methods are called with the incorrect type of event.

This? I'll write an answer later today if that's good enough; if not - what should work differently? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=978ea2f6cb596fdbb76da411a0d47994

I believe there is no way to do it without effectively splitting dispatch. Either you switch on the type of event and in each branch you handle it (like chepner's answer). Or you don't, but then there is no way to get a statically correct Gatherer (like STerliakov's attempt) - it upcasts the gatherer to one that can handle both event types at the same time, but that does not exist. So i vote: not possible under those constraints.

@Wombatz if you're concerned about such "upcast", you can go into gray area of using typevar once in a signature (pyright would need a type: ignore there, mypy accepts as-is). Then _handler_for will return a handler that can only be applied to event itself, and not to any other event. However, that's a bit extreme here IMO. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=1d0f05a1f3b63b53adfcbf24b6a5cae9&flags=strict

Basically it's fine to say "here's an instance that certainly can handle event", even if its static type is broader than necessary - unless you really need to prevent mixing any other event in, my first suggestion should be enough.

The issue here is that I think there are two different types being conflated. Consider the protocol:
T = TypeVar("T", contravariant=True)

class DataGatherer(Generic[T], Protocol):
    def process(self, event: T):
        pass
    def process2(self, event: T):
        pass

We can say DataGathererV1 is a subtype of DataGatherer[EventV1], and DataGathererV2 is a subtype of DataGatherer[EventV2]. So far so good.
The type we need in the dispatch method however, is actually DataGatherer[EventV1 | EventV2] (as this takes both arguments). Since:
DataGatherer[EventV1 | EventV2] != DataGatherer[EventV1] | DataGatherer[EventV2]

...we have an issue.
A Solution
By using a cast, we can convert handler to the type we desire:
from typing import Protocol, overload, TypeVar, Generic, cast

class EventV1:
    pass
class EventV2:
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", contravariant=True)

class DataGatherer(Generic[T], Protocol):
    def process(self, event: T):
        pass
    def process2(self, event: T):
        pass

class DataGathererV1(DataGatherer[EventV1]):
    def process(self, event: EventV1):
        pass
    def process2(self, event: EventV1):
        pass

class DataGathererV2(DataGatherer[EventV2]):
    def process(self, event: EventV2):
        pass
    def process2(self, event: EventV2):
        pass

class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_v1 = DataGathererV1()
        self.worker_v2 = DataGathererV2()

    def dispatch(self, event: EventV1 | EventV2):
        handler = cast(
            DataGatherer[EventV1 | EventV2],
            self.worker_v1 if isinstance(event, EventV1) else self.worker_v2
        )
        handler.process(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process2(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process(event)
        # etc...

You could also use a slightly more generic type for worker_v1 and worker_v2 to circumvent this (although less explicitly):

class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_v1: DataGatherer = DataGathererV1()
        self.worker_v2: DataGatherer = DataGathererV2()

    def dispatch(self, event: EventV1 | EventV2):
        handler: DataGatherer[EventV1 | EventV2] = self.worker_v1 if isinstance(event, EventV1) else self.worker_v2

        handler.process(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process2(event)
        # Common logic

        handler.process(event)
        # etc...


You could also split it into two if blocks, as previously suggested, but otherwise I'm not sure there's any other way to go about it. Hope this is useful!

Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for !

You need to structure your code to make use of type narrowing so that you can execute self.worker_v1 or self.worker_v2 in a context where the specific type of event can be narrowed from EventV1 | EventV2 to either EventV1 or EventV2. Aside from the fact that handler itself isn't known to be DataGatherV1 or DataGatherV2, either class's process method can only handle its specific type, not a value of type EventV1 | EventV2.
def dispatch(self, event: EventV1 | EventV2):
    if isinstance(event, EventV1):
        # static type of event is inferred to be EventV1
        # if we reach this code.

        self.worker_v1.process(event)
        self.worker_v1.process2(event)
        self.worker_v1.process(event)


    else:
        # static type of event is inferred to be EventV2
        # if we reach this code.
        self.worker_v2.process(event)
        self.worker_v2.process2(event)
        self.worker_v2.process(event)

The kind of factoring you want to do simply doesn't work under static typing. You might, however, want to look at functools.singledispatch as well.

You're effectively suggesting to remove the strategy/handler pattern completely: next step for refactoring this if/else would be to move this responsibility to workers, and you are back to OP's problem "I don't want to split dispatch method".
